# Chrome Extension: What is the active tab in 2 opened windows?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that needs to know what URL is on the active tab, but the problem is that when I open a second chrome window there are 2 active tabs, in the webmaster tools it doesn't give me any indication of what window I'm actually on.
[image]
I was actually on the 2nd window when I took this screenshot.

The code that I am using is:

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true}, function (tabs) {
    app.tabInfo = tabs[0];
});
```

But the good code would have been `app.tabInfo = tabs[1];` but I need to know that I need to pick that one. So how can I know?

Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make your query to select the last focused Window:

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
  //...
});
```

*Note*: Better don't take `currentWindow: true` because:

> The current window is the window that contains the code that is currently executing. It's important to realize that this can be different from the topmost or focused window.

<sub>*Source: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#current-window*</sub>

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you very much. But now the problem is that my developer tools doesn't work well because it focuses on that one when I press F5, do you have a way to get over that?

Comment: I am not sure where and how this happens, where do you press F5 and which console is then focused?

Comment: When called from a `browserAction`, this actually looks like a reason to prefer `currentWindow` over `lastFocusedWindow` to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`chrome.windows.getCurrent()`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-getCurrent) (or  `.getLastFocused()`, right below it) to get the current window, then look for the active tab in the `tabs` property of the returned window.

Comment: The current window is the window that contains the code that is currently executing. It's important to realize that this can be different from the topmost or focused window. Source: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#the-current-window