# How do you get all visible tabs in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need to get the tab ids of all VISIBLE tabs in chrome. Note that this is different from currently active tabs or current tab. The user will have the current tab visible, but may have another chrome browser window in the background that may be visible on screen but won't be the current tab. I need the id of that tab as well, and all tabs like it. How can I do this? Can I do this in a way that minimizes permission use (Only using activeTab if possible).

Comment: Simply don't specify the window in chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, tabs => { ...... }) - it won't need `tabs` permission if you don't need urls and other protected stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that first you have to retrieve all the chrome instances.
you can do this with [getAll](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-getAll) method.

Then you can loop over all instances and for each look for the active tabs.
there is a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076408/chrome-extension-what-is-the-active-tab-in-2-opened-windows) related to this, which may help

Comment: My issue is that there seems to be only one active tab at the same time, the one the user last clicked on.

Comment: Basically the idea is to get all the chrome window instances and each of those has a list of tabs, and each tab has properties; one of this properties is called `active` and you should pick only this tabs and do whatever you want...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query).