# How to listen to active tab change cross windows in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In a chrome extension you can listen for tab changes like this

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function (activeInfo) {
    console.log(activeInfo.tabId);
});
```

So, if you select a tab in the same browser window (a browser window has 1 or more tabs), this code wil trigger. But if you have 2 windows (both Chrome), the above code will not trigger if you switch focus between windows. I hoped that this would be also an tab activity change, but its not. So my question is, how can I detect a change in focus between browser windows?

To provide a little bit of context of what I'm trying to achieve: I need the url of the active tab, so if the user switches to an other window, my extension needs to know this and extract the url of the new active tab.

Comment: cross browser in a chrome extension? chrome extensions don't work cross browser, they're for "chrome" - the clue is in the name

Comment: I mean within the same browser, so chrome -> chrome. So you have two chrome windows. Each with tabs open, and I would like a trigger when the users switches windows, not tabs

Comment: oh, - ok - seems intrusive to monitor what a user has open in other tabs though

Comment: I have updated the question a bit to make this more clear

Comment: Maybe you can find something useful is this question: [Chrome Extension: What is the active tab in 2 opened windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076408/chrome-extension-what-is-the-active-tab-in-2-opened-windows). Maybe you can combine with `chrome.windows` to get a trigger when the window is changed?