# Getting active tab information using chrome extension api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension, and I need information about the active tab (when I say "active", I mean the tab that I am looking at in the current window that is focused).

Using the `chrome.tabs` api, I should be able to do something like the following to get what I want:

```
function getActiveTab() {
  var activeTabInfo = {"currentWindow": true, "active" : true};
  return chrome.tabs.query(activeTabInfo,function (tabs) {
    return tabs[0];
  });
}
```

However, when I log the length of `tabs` within the callback, I'm getting a length of 0. I modeled this snippet after [How to fetch URL of current Tab in my chrome extension using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436245/how-to-fetch-url-of-current-tab-in-my-chrome-extension-using-javascript), but can't seem to get it to work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#sync

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Thanks @DanielHerr, those responses definitely helped. Now as a follow-up, what if I _want_ to get a hold of the the return value of an async call in the scope that I presented? Would I have to create some sort of wrapper around the callback in order to be able to do something like the code snippet above?

Comment: Async means it is executed *after* the current scope code runs, as well as its parent callee and so on (i.e. the entire js engine event).