# Get current tab url - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to fetch the URL of current tab using a chrome extension. The extension is a page action extension. So I'm thinking of doing this in `content.js`.

I was trying to use something like below in content.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
    url = new URL(tabs[0].url)
    console.log(`URL: ${url}`)
})
```

However, it appears that `Chrome.tabs` api is not available in `content` scripts.

How can I get the current tab url in `content.js` without having use `background.js` and use message passing from there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436245/how-to-fetch-url-of-current-tab-in-my-chrome-extension-using-javascript

Comment: 1) If your content.js is running in the main page of the tab you can use the web standard `location.href`, otherwise you'll have to use a background page script via messaging. 2) OTOH, a page action is a separate extension page where you can directly use chrome.tabs API, **it's not a web page** so it makes no sense to run content scripts there.