# Some variables are loaded multiple times

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my short coder life I see such behavior for the first time:

An extension at its own works like I expect, but if I pull some variables into the console, I realize, that they are loaded multiple times (three, four and five, depends from placement of `console.log` in the `background.js`). This is the list of them - to see in the `background.js` too:

- `console.log("domen: "+currentDomain);`
- `console.log("language/countrysubdomen: "+savedApi);`
- `console.log("index: "+badgeText);`

Is it something, that one can neglect? Should it be avoided? How? These variables are loaded in file, which is 60 lines long - I was going through this file some times and recognizes no cause for multiple loading.

Why is it happen? What is in the background.js wrong and how it could be improved to get this issue away?

**manifest**

```
{
  "name": " App",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js",
      "psl.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "chrome_style": true,
    "open_in_tab": false
  },
  "permissions": [
    "webNavigation",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "storage",
    "background"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "metrics",
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icon19.png",
      "38": "icon38.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "19": "icon19.png",
    "24": "icon24.png",
    "32": "icon32.png",
    "38": "icon38.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "welcome.html"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background**

```
var currentDomain = "";
var currentHost = "";
var currentFullpath = "";
var currentUrl = "";
var currentFolder = "";
var badgeText = "";

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (object) {
  if (chrome.runtime.OnInstalledReason.INSTALL === object.reason) {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: chrome.extension.getURL("welcome.html") }, function (tab) {
      console.log("New tab launched with instructions to use the extension");
    });
  }
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabid, changeInfo, tab) {
  chrome.tabs.query({ 'active': true, 'currentWindow': true }, function (tabs) {
    let newUrl = new URL(tabs[0].url);
    currentHost = newUrl.host;
    currentUrl = tabs[0].url;
    currentFullpath = currentUrl.substring(0, currentUrl.lastIndexOf("/"));
    currentFolder = currentUrl.split("/");
    parsed = psl.parse(currentHost);
    currentDomain = parsed.domain;

    console.log("domen: " + currentDomain);

    chrome.storage.sync.get('savedApi', ({ savedApi }) => {
      console.log("language/countrysubdomen: " + savedApi);

      if (savedApi == null)
        savedApi = 'de';
      if (currentDomain == null)
        return false;

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var protocol = "https://";
      var middle = ".myservice.com/seo/__loadModule/domain/"
      var end = "/mobile/1/_action/_data_visindex_normal/";

      xhr.open("GET", protocol + savedApi + middle + currentDomain + end, true);

      xhr.responseType = 'document';

      xhr.send();

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
          function getElementByXpath(path) {
            return xhr.response.evaluate(path, xhr.response, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue;
          }

          badgeText = getElementByXpath("normalize-space(//div[@class='data']/span[@class='value']/text())");
          console.log("index: " + badgeText);

          chrome.browserAction.setTitle({ title: "The number of " + currentDomain + " is " + String(badgeText) });
          chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: String(badgeText) });
          chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: '#1d2554' });
        };
      };
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question to put all the relevant code inline. People will be reluctant to follow the google drive links.

Comment: really? Could you maybe explain such unwillingness? Do you mean there are another file hosters, where people aren' such reluctant? Are 120 code lines is not something, what make the post unreadable?

Comment: I am reluctant to follow all external links, and the inline code is placed in scrolling containers here, so it's not a problem.

Comment: @MaxLemieux nice, they are no longer external - something to say about subject?

Comment: It's possible that chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener is firing on repeated "loading/loaded" state changes which occur during a complex page load.

Comment: @MaxLemieux this would mean, there is nothing wrong, which should be fixed, correct? Or are there any other methods to get the current url of an active tab, as with `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener `?

Comment: Updating these variables doesn't seem to be a problem, however it may be possible for you to get the URL without using an event listener - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436245/how-to-fetch-url-of-current-tab-in-my-chrome-extension-using-javascript/58687656#comment39408670_21877205

Comment: @MaxLemieux I need an event listener, because i want to monitor not only initial url, which was opened with tab, but next url user surfs or inputs manually too.

Comment: Seems fine to do this - no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added a listener to `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`, so the listener may be triggered for a number of reasons:

1. a tab begins loading
2. a tab stops loading
3. the title of a tab changes or is set for the first time
4. the favicon is set

This is a non-exhaustive list. For a complete list, see the [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated` event documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated).

It is quite normal that your `onUpdated` listener should be called multiple times. To see why it is being called, insert this line at the top of your listener:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabid, changeInfo, tab) {
  console.log('chrome.tabs.onUpdated listener called. Changed info: ' + JSON.stringify(changeInfo));
```