# How to get active tab index on Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, web-deployment

I'm trying to get the index of my active tab using Javascript for my Google Chrome extension. What should I do?

Comment: 1) get the active tab ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18437759)), 2) read the tab's `index` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help? It also depends on where it is executed from. This snippet is executed on a window event from popup.

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(
        tabs[0].id,
        { code: <your code> });
});
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. This is a brilliant solution.